# Error django_session

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Estoy desplegando mi aplicación y cuando trato de hacer login me da este error, mi aplicación trabaja con 2 base de datos 1 con `postgresql` y la otra sql server que se encuentra en un servidor externo, los usuarios están en la base de datos `postgres`, este es el error:

> relation "django_session" does not exist
>   LINE 1: ...ession_data", "django_session"."expire_date" FROM "django_se...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Busqué y encontré una solución, había que hacer primero `migrate --database nombreBD` y después `migrate` solo y funcionó a la perfección.